# How to implement _mm_and_ps?

Tags: c++, floating-point, bitwise-operators, intrinsics

I am trying to implement `_mm_and_ps` using float values. The [documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_and_ps&expand=291) says this function is the bitwise of 4 *single precision* floating point numbers, but I am not sure how to calculate the bitwise of 2 floating point numbers. Basically I want to implement the following

```
vector<float> bitwise_and(vector<float>a ,vector<float> b){
    assert(a.size()==4);
    assert(b.size()==4);
    vector<float> res(4);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        res[i]=a[i]&b[i]; //here is the problem
    return res;

}
```

Comment: `__m128` is a SIMD vector, not a `std::vector` variable-length container.  `__m128` is more closely modeled by `std::array<float,4>`.  Also, you don't have to implement it; you just use it.  Is looks like you want to write a portable alternative.  Anyway yes, it does a bitwise AND of the IEEE754 FP bit patterns.  (x86 uses IEEE FP).

Answer (score 1):

You can access each bytes of data via `char*` pointer.

```
vector<float> bitwise_and(vector<float>a ,vector<float> b){
    assert(a.size()==4);
    assert(b.size()==4);
    vector<float> res(4);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof(float); j++)
            reinterpret_cast<char*>(&res[i])[j]=
                reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a[i])[j]&
                reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b[i])[j];
    return res;

}
```

Another way is to use `union` to access memory for `float` as `int` (assuming `int` has same size as `float`)

```
vector<float> bitwise_and(vector<float>a ,vector<float> b){
    assert(a.size()==4);
    assert(b.size()==4);
    assert(sizeof(float)==sizeof(int));
    vector<float> res(4);
    union hoge { float fl; int in; };
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        hoge res_h, a_h, b_h;
        a_h.fl = a[i];
        b_h.fl = b[i];
        res_h.in = a_h.in & b_h.in;
        res[i] = res_h.fl;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: ISO C++ doesn't guarantee C99-style union type-punning.  Mainstream C++ compilers do define the behaviour, though.  (All that support GNU extensions, and MSVC at least).  C++20 finally added non-horrible syntax for type-punning with `<bit>` for [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast).